# Sessions in sinatra app being shared across browsers

Tags: ruby, session, web-applications, sinatra

I'm using Sinatra framework to make a very simple web app that requires a session for login.

I can login just fine, but when my friends visit the site they are logged in as me. I had a friend sign-up. When I re-visited the site I was logged in as her!! We're 3000 miles apart on different devices.

Here is the gist of my login code..

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

# I have tried enabling/disabling the :session_secret
# set :session_secret, 'my_secret' 
enable :sessions

before '*' do
  begin
    User.login(User.find(session[:me])) if session[:me]
  end
end

post '/login' do
  user = User.find_by_email!(params[:email]).authenticate!(params[:password])
  session[:me] = user.id
  User.login user
  200
end
```

I also tried adding this to my rackup file

```
use Rack::Session::Cookie, 
    :key => 'my_app_key',
    :path => '/',
    :expire_after => 14400, # seconds
    :secret => 'secret_stuff'
```

The issue is both on production and development environments.

Sinatra documentation does not recommend any config beyond `enable :sessions`
http://www.sinatrarb.com/faq.html#sessions

Comment: What's `User.login` look like?

Comment: `def login(user); @@me = user; end` nothing of interest really

Comment: That's of _major_ interest... `@@me` is a class variable which retains it's value in the class and has a lifespan which would _span multiple requests_... So that might be your very problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
User.login(User.find(session[:me])) if session[:me]

class User
  def self.login(user)
    @@me = user
  end
end
```

Here's your problem. Class variables persist, even between requests.

1. You login
2. `User` `@@me` gets set to your user
3. Someone elses visits the site.
4. `session[:me]` is `nil` since there is no session yet
5. `User.login` is not called, which would either set `User` `@@me` to a user or to nil.

So when there is no `session[:me]`, `User` `@@me` doesn't get changed.

In short, *do not* use class variables to store information that should only persist for a single request.

Comment: Very interesting. This is how I store "static" information to the User class in PHP apps. Where should this information be stored in Sinatra? Is env accessible from `class User`?

Comment: If you _really_ want the `User` class to know who's currently logged in, Be sure the wipe the `@@me` immediately at the start of _every_ request `session[:me] ? User.login(User.find(session[:me])) : User.login(nil)`.  Otherwise, you save the user id in the session and create an instance variable for the `@current_user` and pass it around. This is typically how rails works, but I'm not sure if Sinatra has different conventions.

Comment: Is that not going to be an issue for concurrent requests? (since it seems separate requests "share" `@@me`)

Comment: @jchook It depends. Typically, ruby based webapps are synchronous for a single request, and concurrency is handled by having multiple ruby processes. Each process has it's own classes and class variables, so that's not a problem. But that's not always the case, and it can be tricky. So it's best just to not statically store the current user at all. Make an instance in the controller and pass it around.